# Jenkins maven build test failure for Sikuli dependency with Selenium

Tags: selenium, maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I have created Maven project in eclipse with Selenium & TestNG to create automation test scripts which I want to execute from Jenkins.
I am getting below error while building it.

```
Failed to collect dependencies at com.sikulix:sikulixapi:jar:1.1.0 -> jxgrabkey:jxgrabkey:jar:1.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for jxgrabkey:jxgrabkey:jar:1.0: Could not transfer artifact jxgrabkey:jxgrabkey:pom:1.0 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [uni-due.de (http://mvn.is.inf.uni-due.de:8081/nexus/content/repositories/atunes-dependencies/, default, releases)]
```

I have given this `test -Dbrowser="Chrome"` in goals and options

Please do the helpful.
I'm using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId
    <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Update the question with the Sikuli dependency you are using.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium- added the Sikuli dependency

Comment: The problem is the blocked mirror because you are using http instead https ... Details: https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html

Comment: Sikuli v1.1.0 looks ancient, can you try Sikuli v1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the latest [Maven Sikuli dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sikuli/sikuli-api/1.2.0):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sikuli/sikuli-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikuli-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```